# Set range to a cell via .find method

Tags: vba, set, range

I want to assign the "pointer" range object to a cell that should be determined through the .find method plus offsetting that found address by 3 rows via .offset method.
I seem to be doing something wrong with the following code:

```
With Sheets("Database")

    Dim pointer As Range
    Set pointer = .Cells.Find("string data").Offset(3)
    ...

End With
```

I keep getting Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: [Range.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) has some interesting parameters that may help, e. g. `LookIn` and `LookAt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get that error because `.Cells.Find("string data")` returns `Nothing`. 
To avoid this error, you could introduce a **check**, like this:

```
Dim pointer As Range

With Sheets("Database")
    If Not .Cells.Find("string data") Is Nothing Then
        Set pointer = .Cells.Find("string data").Offset(3)
    End If
End With
'...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That was indeed the problem.
One more question regarding a similar problem:

Set searchRng = Range("pointer.address:.cells(pointer.End(xlDown).Row,pointer.Column).address")
is failing as well for a different reason. What am i doing wrong here? Sorry for the trivial questions, im new to VBA...

Comment: Error 1004: Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: @Ardnic Sorry, I wasn't available. I suggest you to post another question (in case you already didn't), I'm sure someone can help you with this :)